# Java subclass implementation mandatory constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Is there any way in Java to enforce a subclass or interface implementation to have a constructor with a given signature?

Let's say that I´ve got either:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    // any methods
}
```

or

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
    // any abstract methods
}
```

Now, is it possible to do anything to require

```
public class MySubClass extends MyBaseClass {
    public MySubClass(String s) { }
}
```

or

```
public class MySubClass implements MyInterface {
    public MySubClass(String s) { }
}
```

to always have a constructor that takes a String as it´s only input parameter?

The obvious workaround is to create a factory interface with a method taking a String and inject it where required. Which is not what I would like to do.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can write unit tests to check (with reflection) that all the classes implementing the interface have a constructor accepting a string, but it's not clear what benefit you're expecting here. Might some classes want to have constructors that require *more* than just a string? Might some classes effectively hard code whatever the string is used for? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: No, you can force subclasses to have a specific constructor, and why would you care?

Comment: @ivan
Even if you create a base class with only one public constructor with the desired signature you can still create a subclass which lacks such constructor like:

`
public class ParentClass {
 private ParentClass() { }
 public ParentClass(String s) { }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
 public ChildClass(int i) {
  super(String.valueOf(i));
 }
}
`

Comment: @jon-skeet
Imagine that you have an abstract DataSource.
Each DataSource connects to a db with a connection string from a list.
There are different DataSource implementations injected externaly.
And there is a method that returns a collection of data sources of a given subclass.
`
public <D extends DataSource> Collection<D> getDataSources(Class<D> implClass, String[] connectionStrings) throws Exception {
 Collection<D> sources = new ArrayList<>();
 for (String conn  : connectionStrings)
  sources.add(implClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(conn));
 return sources;
}
`

Comment: @SergMTen: At the point where you're using reflection, any number of things could go wrong that the language couldn't help you with. The fact that you *have* to use reflection for that means you're beyond areas where the language tries to help you with interfaces. But it also means you can easily write a unit test to validate it anyway.

Comment: For that case you could perfectly use a `Function<String, D>` instead of `Class<D>` and use `function.apply(conn)`. There's never a need to enforce constructors, as creation of objects is something independent of the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, the closest I think you can get is something like:

```
abstract class B {

    public B(String s) {
    }
}

public class A extends B {
    public A(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

This forces A to implement a non default constructor which must call `super(String)` but can not prevent the following:

```
public class A extends B {
    public A() {
        super("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There have been many times where I wished something like this existed, but sadly  it doesn't. Even something like what David Soroko suggested wouldn't work because a subclass still wouldn't be forced to have a String constructor - it can just pass any String it likes to `super`. Simply put, there is no such thing within the Java syntax itself.

I suppose the closest one could get to such a capability is if someone built an annotation processor that allows you to use an annotation like `@MustHaveUnaryConstructor(String.class)` and then if any subclass does not have such a constructor, it causes compilation to fail and tells you which subclass broke the contract. But I haven't found such a thing and I don't know enough about annotation processing to build one myself. So TL;DR, no, you can't.